# How to create bootstrap columns in a list of bootstrap thumbnails

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm not sure if bootstrap thumnails are the best component to use here, so if there is someone who can suggest something else please do. Here is what I want - a list of items that look something like this in a column that will represent results returned from the server. But when I add 4 columns inside the thumbnail the text and column divs don't fit into the thumbnails seen in the second pic. My code is below the pics.

[image]

[image]

```html
<style>
.thumbnail .col-lg-3 {
    border: 1px solid red;
    
}
.searchResults {
        height: 85%;
        border: 1px solid green;
        overflow-y: scroll
    }
</style>

<div class="searchResults col-lg-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
  <div class="thumbnail">
    <div class="col-lg-3">
      <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
      <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
      <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
      <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
      <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
      <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
      <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
      <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="thumbnail">
    <div class="col-lg-3">
      <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
      <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
      <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
      <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
      <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
      <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
      <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
      <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Adding the class `row` to your `thumbnail` `<div>` should fix it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per Boostrap

- Use rows to create horizontal groups of columns.

That being said, you can just add the class of `row` to your existing `<div class="thumbnail">` div.

It should look something like this:

```
<div class="thumbnail row">
  <div class="col-lg-3">
    ...
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3">
    ...
  </div>  
  <div class="col-lg-3">
    ...
  </div>  
  <div class="col-lg-3">
    ...
  </div>  
</div>
```

Here's a fiddle demo for you to review. http://jsfiddle.net/9ndyzzaf/

Comment: Thanks but I have some css that sets the row class to a height: 100%, so when I use thumbnail row as a class the thumbnail gets set to the entire height of the surrounding div. how can I override this for your answer so that the thumbnail becomes its default height?

Comment: also I don't want to set a specific height like 300px because I want the thumbnail to be somewhat responsive when I resize.

Comment: `.thumbnail { height: auto !important; }`, that will overwrite your row class height value. *I don't want to set a specific height like 300px because I want the thumbnail to be somewhat responsive when I resize.* Why not just use padding or use bootstraps `img-responsive` class for the `<img>` tag. http://getbootstrap.com/css/#images-responsive

Comment: If you don't want to use `!important`, you can also specify it this way `.thumbnail.row { height: auto; }`.

Comment: what would be the difference between using !important and not? and I think I will use 'img-responsive' when I insert an image into the thumbnail, but I haven't done that yet. Isn't 'img-responsive' only for images?

Comment: When an `!important` is used on a style declaration, this declaration overrides any other declaration made in the CSS, wherever it is in the declaration list. Using `!important` is considered bad practice and should be avoided because it makes debugging more difficult, it's why I suggested `.thumbnail.row { ... }`. And Yes, `img-responsive` is primarily for images.